# Get SGE jobid to make a pipeline

Tags: cluster-computing, pipeline, sungridengine

Suppose I want to write a pipeline of tasks to submit to Sun/Oracle Grid Engine.

```
qsub -cwd touch a.txt
qsub -cwd -hold_jid touch wc -l a.txt
```

Now, this will run the 2nd job (wc) only after the first job (touch) is done. However, if a previous job with the name touch had run earlier, the 2nd job won't be held since the condition is already satisfied. I need the jobid of the first job.

I tried

```
myjid=`qsub -cwd touch a.txt`
```

But it gave `$ echo $myjid
Your job 1062487 ("touch") has been submitted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the `-terse` option to the first `qsub` so that it only displays the jobid rather than the whole string.

```
JID=`qsub -terse -cwd touch a.txt`
```